# How can I access properties/methods of the DataContext used to populate a XAML class from the code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, savefiledialog

I want to use the SaveFileDialog in the code behind to write a file using data that is contained in the ViewModel. The XAML class I am working with is populated by a selection made in a listbox in the parent class:

```
    <Views:ChildView DataContext="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=childrenListbox}"></Views:ChildView >
```

Then, within the ChildView XAML file I am able to freely access properties/methods of the ChildViewModel as expected. However, I don't know how to access them from the code behind. I have a "Save File" button

```
    <Button Content="Save File" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

whose event is handled in the code behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document";
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            //Here I would like to call the SaveFile function in ChildViewModel
        }
    }
```

I have tried looking through all the available properties but I cannot find a way to access the instance of ChildViewModel that I am working with. This question might have a simple solution, but I am not familiar with using the code-behind because I am making my first guild and I have been using the MVVM approach. I will strongly appreciate any answers that help me find a working solution. Also, please feel free to criticize me for using the code behind with MVVM if there is a way to avoid it and get a SaveFileDialog by only using XAML (then I could easily do the file saving within the ModelView).

Comment: There won't be a XAML-only way of doing this, but you can add the reference to Microsoft.Win32 to your ViewModel, bind the button to a Command in that same ViewModel (instead of the click event), and do the save in the ViewModel itself.

Comment: It is considered bad to do things in the codebehind. Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Please have a look at my answer on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure where you are setting your ViewModel because you did not show the code for it, but usually it sits on the `DataContext` property of your root element.
So you could just cast it like that.

```
var viewModel = (ChildViewModel)this.DataContext;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try a different approach:

Get a command for your button

```
public abstract class MyCommandBase : ICommand
{
    public abstract bool CanExecute(object o);
    public abstract void Execute(object o);

    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}


public class ButtonClickCommand : MyCommandBase
{
    public ButtonClickCommand(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        base.ViewModel = vm;
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object o)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void Execute(object o)
    {
        var context = this.ViewModel as MyViewModel;
        MessageBox.Show("Button was clicked for" + context.Id);
    }
}
```

Build an instance of that command in your ViewModel and make a public property for that.

And in your XAML it is just

```
<Button Focusable="False" Command="{Binding CmdClickMyButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
```

That way, when a button is clicked, you are directly back in your ViewModel,
having all information you need. Saving data to a file is a nonissue.

Comment: Good answer, although I am not entirely sold on your implementation of ButtonClickCommand (for instance, always setting CanExecute to true, or requiring a ViewModel instance).  I generally prefer the [Josh Smith approach.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: this is an example. I wanted it to bring it as close to productive as possible. But I like the linked approach also, but in my example it would be too much I think. Just want to get OP out of the code-behind. ;)

Comment: I will try switching over to your solution to avoid using the code behind.

Comment: Fair enough, and the link to Josh Smith's code is here for the OP to look at, too.  :)

Comment: You are welcome! This is the "MVVM approach" of doing such things

Comment: If this was helpful for you, feel free and accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help:

`((YourViewModelClass)YourControl.DataContext).SaveFile();`

Regards

**EDIT:**

Acording to your example:

`((ChildViewModel)ChildView.DataContext).SaveFile();`

if you want this code in the ChildView's code-behind it would be:

`((ChildViewModel)this.DataContext).SaveFile();`

Comment: What would "YourControl" be? The SaveFile() is not a static method so I need to use the correct instance of my view model class.

Comment: Yes, the `DataContext` property gets the instance of the viewModel you are currently using. The control is, in your case, `ChildView`. I wiil edit my answer

Comment: Ok that works, sorry for asking for such detail, I'm new to C#/XAML/WPF.